# Handling OAuth2 Authorization Code Flow Response client-side

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0

As stated in the title, I'm trying to use OAuth's Authorization Code Flow to generate access tokens.

If my understanding is correct the flow works roughly like this:

1. Client sends user with authorization request to identity provider
2. User authenticates and authorizes client
3. Identity Provider redirects User back to callback from client
4. Client retrieves code from response
5. Client exchanges code for token through backroute

The steps work until the redirect back to the client's `/callback` endpoint, where I dont know how to retrieve the code from the response.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the javascript app checks its URL when it loads. If it is a login response, the app retrieves the code query parameter and writes code to send an Ajax POST.

See [my code example](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/app/app.ts#L48) or run it yourself by following [this blog post](https://authguidance.com/basicspa-execution/). In this example I am using a library to do the POST to swap the code for tokens:

```js
private async _handleLoginResponse(): Promise<void> {

    const urlData = urlparse(location.href, true);
    if (urlData.query && urlData.query.state) {
        await this._userManager.signinRedirectCallback();
}
```